# Routing in VUE.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

So I have a routes.js file to handle my routing in my VUE app and I have used it to transition between components successfully using a router-link tag. However I would now like to execute routes using javascript. For example after I receive an authentication response from my server I would like to transition from the login page to my home page. What can I do to execute a route when I want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically route using `router.push('home')`. [Here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html) is a a reference to see more options available.

Comment: I wasnt refering to the router correctly because I was inside of a VUE instance I needed to use this.$router.push(location, onComplete?,onAbort?)